# Cannot submit hackerrank problem for determining score change

Tags: python

I am trying to complete a hackerrank problem where given an array, I have  determined the amount of times a number in the array is greater than the latest max number or the latest min number. The max/min at the beginning are both equal to the first number of the array.

The corresponding problem can be found at this hackerrank [link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/breaking-best-and-worst-records/problem).

I tried implementing successful solutions from other people but the solution is not being accepted as success in the hackerrank system. I am not sure what is going wrong.

```
def breakingRecords(scores):
    max_score = min_score = scores[0]
    mini = maxi = 0
    for i in range(1,len(scores)):
        if scores[i] > max_score:
            max_score = scores[i]
            maxi += 1
        if scores[i] < min_score:
            min_score = scores[i]
            mini += 1
    return str(maxi) + str(mini)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it hasn't worked"?

Comment: It says you're supposed to print the two numbers separated by a space. You don't have a space between the numbers.

Comment: @kurag The summary here of the problem isn't correct. If you read the problem description at hackerrank, you're supposed to count the number of times a number is greater(less) than the maximum(minimum) so far, not the overall max(min). It's about how many times you've established a new personal best or worst.

Comment: In fact, your interpretation makes no sense. There can't be any numbers higher than the max, because then it wouldn't be the max.

Comment: I might have explained it a bit weirdly, but if you were to look at my code, you would see that the max/min is supposed to be the first number, and you would have to count the amount of times that a number is either lower than the min or max. The max/min keeps changing based on each number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your return statement to

```
return maxi, mini
```

The addition of string means concatenation. We can't tell if 123 means (12, 3) or (1, 23).

Note that there are other lines of the code in the submission that helps you with the submission.

```
fptr.write(' '.join(map(str, result)))
```

converts each element of result to string and then then introduce a blank space as the separator.